# Array Key:Value Not Outputting Element Name

Tags: php, arrays, key-value

I'm creating an array from a database and its being created correctly as seen below.

```
array(2) { 
    ["members"]=> bool(true) 
    ["maps"]=> bool(true) 
}
```

The issue is when I output the array using key:value the key is outputting the element number for example 0 for 'members and 1 for 'maps'.

```
foreach($vPrivileges as $vKey => $vValue) {
   echo "$vKey: $vValue";
}
```

I need to output the actual name of the element and the value, I've spent awhile looking online and trying out some code samples but haven't been able to find a solution, any help is greatly appreciated.

Also I noticed that if I take the array and use the `sort()` function on it, it sorts as expected with one exception that it renames all the array elements to 0, 1 etc.

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> bool(true) 
    [1]=> bool(true) 
}
```

Comment: `sort()` sorts by values, since your array contains boolean values it's sorted in a weird way. Is that what you're trying to do? Also, do you have that problem after sorting the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [asort](http://php.net/asort) instead of sort to preserve array keys. This will fix your problem (assuming you call sort before the foreach-loop).